# How to write text under underline in itext7

Tags: pdf, itext7, underline

I want text in pdf under underline. I am using itext7. How to make it?
Will be thankfull if someone point right direction to this problem. Thanks in advance.

I have a word office document. There are underlines which will be filled manually after printing on paper. Under each underlines there is annotation text which describe what needed to write out.
I try to reproduce this word office document in pdf format using itext7. Everything ok except this annotation texts under underlines. I have googled it, but maybe I have used wrong search keys I have not found solution. Now I am not sure if is it possible to do.

[image: https://ibb.co/qsd5xkH]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fairly easy to implement using text rise setting which is a standard setting in PDF. Below is a brief code sample:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.add("The beginning of the line ");
p.add(new Text("          (fill in your name)          ").setTextRise(-10).setUnderline().setFontSize(8));
p.add(" end of the line");
```

And here is how the output looks like if you add this paragraph to a document:

[image]

Comment: Nice solution! Thank you very much @Alexey Subach. You saved my month!

Comment: do you know how to write text under text? This is the same problem but now I need to write text above underline programmatically.